# Como definir a localização de Jbutton conforme o tamanho de um Panel

Tags: java, swing

Eu gostaria de definir a localização do `color1` conforme o tamanho de um JPanel, do mesmo jeito que fiz com o `fundo`

```
public static void janelaPrincipal()
{
    //FRAME
    JFrame janela = new JFrame();
    janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    janela.pack();
    janela.setResizable(false);
    janela.setVisible(true);
    janela.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));   
    janela.setLocation((SCREEN.width / 2) - (WIDTH / 2), (SCREEN.height / 2) - (HEIGHT / 2));

    Container c = janela.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //PAINEIS
    JPanel fundo = new JPanel();

    fundo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    fundo.setBackground(background);

    //BOTOES
    JButton color1 = new JButton();
    JButton color2 = new JButton();

    color1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTHBUTTON, HEIGHTBUTTON));
    color1.setLocation(HEIGHT / 2, WIDTH /2);
    color1.setBackground(RED);

    //ADICIONAR NO FRAME
    c.add(fundo);
    fundo.add(color1);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Você quer manter seu JButton sempre no centro da sua JPanel e não está conseguindo, é isso?

Comment: Não, o centro foi apenas um exemplo, eu quero posicionar por "pixels" do mesmo jeito que posicionei o Jframe na tela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão principal deveria ser: **Porque é que queres posicionar de forma absoluta os teus componentes?**

As interfaces em Java têm a possibilidade de ser executadas num vasto número de plataformas, com diferentes resoluções de ecrã e utilizando diferentes [PLAFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_look_and_feel). Por estas razões, o posicionamento absoluto de componentes não é a melhor das práticas. Para construires uma GUI robusta e que mantenha o mesmo aspecto independentemente das definições do dispositivo onde está a correr, eu sugeriria a utilização de um *layout manager*, ou vários, em conjunto com *preenchimento (padding)* e margens para espaços em branco de forma a organizar os componentes.

Se ainda assim pretenderes controlar manualmente o posicionamento do botão basta remover o Layout do componente onde colocaste o botão através do método `setLayout(null)`. Após remover o layout podes usar a mesma lógica usada para o JPanel.

Aqui fica um exemplo muito simples de como podes fazer para colocar o botão numa posição específica da janela:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainForm {

    protected JFrame  janela = new JFrame("Teste");
    protected JButton color1 = new JButton("Exemplo");

    public static void main(String st[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                MainForm mf = new MainForm();
                mf.load();
            }
        });

    }
    public void load() {

    janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        janela.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));   
        janela.setResizable(false);
    janela.setVisible(true);

    Container c = janela.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(null); //vamos fazer a gestão manualmente
    color1.setBounds(250, 50, 150, 50); //dimensoes e posicionamento do botão (os dois primeiros valores indicam a posicao absoluta do botao)
    c.add(color1);
    }
```

}

Sugiro ainda a leitura de https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html